# Is it possible to update a live tile without the Windows Push Notification Service?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to update a live tile without the Windows Push Notification Service? I would like to create an offline clock live tile.

Comment: Have you seen this MSDN documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to update Tiles without push notifications. You can use background agent, but it is executed on 30 minutes(in WP7.5) and you can not implement tile clock.

Here is a nice post how to implement live tiles from background agents:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.5-Use-Background-agents.aspx

Comment: FYI: if you develop application for yourself, you can use `Background Agent` with any interval with `LaunchForTest` method. But this application will not be certified on Marketplace. There is `Tile World Clock` app was developed already, you can find it in xda

Comment: LaunchForTest is an option but as you mantioned app can not be published on the Marketplace and executing background tasks with custom interval is not yet officially supported.